# SQL retrieve data where in interval of one column

Tags: sql

In my table I have a column `tranche`, and the values of this column look like this:

```
01-03
04-06
07-08
```

This column is of type `varchar`; I want to retrieve row where my data is included in `tranche`, example if I enter "5", I want to retrieve the row that has `tranche= 04-06`.

**UPDATED**
this the example of data [image: db] on my table. When i give `5` my data is between 5 and 6 so i want to retrieve the third row as the `tranche` column value us `'05-06'`, and if give `2` i want the first row;

Comment: You want to compare data in a row against a text range in the same row?

Comment: my column value is varchar '01-03' '04-06' etc..., and i want to compare if my given data is on '01-03' or else, if i give 5 , i should got the row that have column value '04-06'

Comment: please tag your dbms

Comment: updated my topics

Comment: `£where X between cast(left(tranche, 2) as int) and cast(right(tranche, 2) as int)`